# Positioning links within jCarousel

Tags: css, jcarousel

I have problems laying out the jCarousel pager (which I'm using along with Colorbox on a Drupal site). My goal is to butt up the back/fwd links against the left/right edges of the panel. The problem is that when I use position:absolute, the prev link stops working. Has anybody managed to struggle through this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase the z-index of the links. Because the prev-link is sitting behind the sliding elements, you are seeing it but, cannot click on it.

Comment: How come I forgot ;-) Bingo! Cannot get the thumbs to trigger Colorbox though, but this might be a more complex, Drupal-related issue.